# Issue with react app webpack5 configuration when creating build pipelines in azure devops

Tags: reactjs, webpack, azure-devops

Below is my build command,

```
 "build": "webpack --mode=production --config webpack.prod.js",
```

Below is my webpack related packages,

```
"webpack": "^5.11.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
"webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
```

Below is webpack.prod.js,

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
mode: 'production',
});
```

In local build command is working fine but Getting below error in pipelines,

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
at Function.getCompilationHooks (....\Web\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:171:10)
at ...\Web\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\HotModuleReplacementPlugin.js:705:18
```

[image]

Comment: If local build is working, check if the `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` file is identical on local and on the deployed version.

Comment: package-lock.json i updated latest.still same issue

Comment: what do you mean you updated latest? do you mean the `package-lock.json` files are the exact same version?

Comment: both package-lock.json are same

Comment: I have updated logs screenshot. In case if it hepls

Comment: Not expert in Webpack5, but I have checked this error in some threads, and found that it seems that webpack5 doesn't work fine with html-webpack-plugin 4, you could run command ```npm uninstall html-webpack-plugin``` and then ```npm i html-webpack-plugin@5.0.0-alpha.9``` to check the result. Also you could  run ```npm install webpack-cli@3.3.12``` and use it(3.3.12) in package.json to check the result. See: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1451 for details.

Comment: I am not using html-webpack-plugin anywhere. I am not using that package at all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, local build environment is different from [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), so if your project build result depends on build environment, you'd better [deploy self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install), which will run on your local environment.

If you still want to use [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), you can see the installed software for each hosted agent by choosing the **Included Software** link in the table.
[image] And then compare it with local build environment, to decide to install other required software/libraries/packages or specific software version to build your project.